# How to remove library from memory in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

There are multi libraries that each of them generates some HTML elements which runs separately such that by running one library first the elements created by the previous library must be removed then new elements will generated.
It's worked fine, the elements removed correctly and new ones created correctly.

But there is a problem : the previous library that runs, again exist in the memory and listen to events. How can I dispose that from memory ?

```
import { LeftSidebarEditor } from './editor/LeftSidebar.Editor.js';
import { LeftSidebarSupport } from './support/LeftSidebar.Support.js';

function LeftSidebar(editor) {

    var signals = editor.signals;

    var container = new UIPanel();
    container.setId('left-sidebar-menu');

    var item = new LeftSidebarEditor(editor);

    container.add(item);

    signals.scopeChanged.add(function (scope) {

        editor.currentScope = JSON.stringify(scope);
        // remove all elements
        container.clear();

        item = null;

        switch (scope) {

             case 'editor':
                // container.add(new LeftSidebarEditor(editor));
                item = new LeftSidebarEditor(editor);

                container.add(item);
                break;

            case 'support':
                // container.add(new LeftSidebarSupport(editor));
                item = new LeftSidebarSupport(editor);

                container.add(item);
                break;

        }

    });

    return container;

}
```

#### LeftSidebarSupport

```
class LeftSidebarSupport {

    constructor(editor) {

        let counter = 0;
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log('I am alive from support', counter++);
        }, 2000);

         signals.objectSelected.add(function (object) {

        if (object != null) {

            return;
        }

        const selected = document.querySelector('#left-sidebar-menu li.selected');
        if (selected){
            let selected_attr =  selected.getAttribute('data-tooltip');
            if (selected_attr!='Tag'){
                removeAllSelected();
            }
        }

    });


        function removeAllSelected() {

        const selected = document.querySelector('#left-sidebar-menu li.selected');

        if (selected) {

            selected.classList.remove('selected');

        }

    }

    }
}
```

By change the signal from `support` to `editor` again the logs printed which must be stopped !!
I want by switching between scopes just exist current scope library in memory and others removed entirely.

```
I am alive from support 89
I am alive from support 90
I am alive from support 91
I am alive from support 92
I am alive from support 93
```

#### Pleas, note !

There really is no interval, but exist a piece of code that removes a class from the elements.
For simplicity, the interval example is used here.
The basis of my question is why can LeftSidebarSupport running again?

Comment: The `setInterval` is not bound to a `LeftSidebarSupport` instance. You need to store the value returned from `setInterval` and create a new method on `LeftSidebarSupport` which calls `clearInterval` to stop it.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier There really is no interval, but exist a piece of code that removes a class from the elements
For simplicity, the interval example is used here.
The basis of my question is why can LeftSidebarSupport running again?

Comment: It's hard to say without actually seeing what  the`LeftSidebarSupport` code looks like. Does it contain event listeners?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I update my question and added LeftSidebarSupport

Comment: It's not possible to remove a loaded script from the memory. Even when you use modules, the entire script file is loaded. I suppose your only change is to include some kind of a reset function to the modules, that should remove the event listeners and abort the timeouts/intervals it has created. If these libraries are from a third-party, you're much out of luck. You might also change the design, reload the page, and deliver the information of the current state within the URL, or store the state into Local Storage. Then using the state you can re-create the page, and load the needed module.

Comment: @Teemu This is a fact that I did not want to believe !!

Comment: I can understand that, but that's how the scripts are designed to work. If there's not a ton of the event listeners, as the first aid you could try to replace the listened elements with a clone, that would remove the event listeners without having to reload the page.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu , I will implement your suggested methods .